# Mount AWS S3 on boot while behind proxy using s3fs

Tags: s3fs

In order to get a mount to work I have to first set the http_proxy environment variable before I run s3fs.

```
export https_proxy=<proxy address>
s3fs -d <bucket> mount-point -o url=https://s3.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com -o use_path_request_style
```

I'd like to mount my S3 bucket on boot but I am behind a proxy.  I can add it to fstab, but it doesnt work because it doesnt know about the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this using a [systemd initialisation script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319267/systemd-how-to-make-a-systemd-service-start-after-network-fully-connected).

You can control which order these run, by configuring the 'After' deceleration.

For example, using the following line should allow you to run a command after the network is up:

`After=network-online.target`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround can you add a shell wrapper script that sets the environment variable then involves the real s3fs binary?  I opened an issue to track direct support:

https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/2069